# Can extinction probabilities be negative?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Bacteria reproduce by cell division. In a unit of time, a bacterium will either
die (with, $p=\frac{1}{4}$), stay the same (with, $p=\frac{1}{4}$), or split into 2
parts (with, $p=\frac{1}{2}$). The population starts with 100 bacteria at time
$n = 0$.
What is the extinction probability for this population?

I have calculated $E(a^y)=a$
and, got $a= -\frac{1}{2}$ and $a=1$.

Which should I accept as I know you are meant to pick the smallest answer but it does not make sense how a probability could be negative?

Comment: Negative probabilities do not make sense , sadly it is claimed that they play a role in quantum mechanics.

Comment: what is $a$ and what is $y$ in your formula?

Comment: a is the extinction probability the formula is E[a^y]=a